# How to collect Kubernetes Metadata?

Tags: kubernetes, metadata

I am looking for a way to get all object's metadata within a k8s cluster and send it out to an external server.

By metadata, I refer to objects `Name`, `Kind`, `Labels`, `Annotations`, etc.
The intention is to build an offline inventory of a cluster.

What would be the best approach to build it? Is there any tool that already does something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Just use k8s client in language of your choice and make a bunch of requests.

Comment: You can find available kubernetes clients [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/)

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

There are different ways to achieve it.

1. From this [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151#issuecomment-402003022) it's possible to iterate through all resources to get all available objects.

   in **yaml**:

   ```
   kubectl api-resources --verbs=list -o name   | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -o yaml
   ```

   in **json**:

   ```
   kubectl api-resources --verbs=list -o name   | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -o json
   ```

   And then parse the output.
2. Use kubernetes clients.

   There are already developed [kubernetes clients](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) (available for different languages) which can be used to get required information and work with it later.
3. Use kubectl plugin - `ketall` (didn't test it)

   There's a developed plugin for kubectl which returns **all** cluster resources. Please find [github repo - ketall](https://github.com/corneliusweig/ketall). Again after cluster objects are gotten, you will need to parse/work with them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this commands

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces -o yaml
```

or

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces -o json
```

you can parse and use as you find fit

Comment: This is an incorrect answer, `kubectl get all` does not return ALL resources, only some general kinds. See [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151)

Comment: @moonkotte this issue refers to listing resources in a particular namespace issue. --all-namespaces will make sure to list down all resources in all namepsaces of all kind

Comment: Did you run this command before posting the comment? Are you sure it works the way you're saying? Because even `kubectl - Client Version: v1.22.3` returns only general kinds (like pods, deployments, daemonsets, statefulsets, services) and it doesn't return any CRDs, nor even configmaps, secrets, pv/pvc.